# How to configure sshd to automatically launch ssh-agent and add user ssh keys, without user typing password twice?

Tags: server, ssh

My server is currently running Ubuntu 20.04.4.  I work in an environment where most users use their login password to encrypt their ssh keys.  (Yes, I am aware this is not as secure as possible.  This is the point we've chosen on the convenience/security spectrum.)  I would like to configure `sshd` on my server so that when users log in, it automatically launches `ssh-agent`, and adds their ssh keys to `ssh-agent` (as if they had typed `ssh-add` just after logging in), *without the user having to type their password twice when they login*.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

(To be clear, I want to do this so that, once a user is logged into the machine running the sshd server, they can then do passwordless ssh into other machines in the building.)

Comment: @user68186 Once the user logs into the remote, they may then want to ssh into other remote computers, so they want to add their ssh keys in ~/.ssh on the remote to an ssh-agent running on the remote.  In fact this is pretty common in the environment I'm talking about.

Comment: Basically because of all the reasons listed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/what-benefit-is-there-to-adding-a-password-to-your-ssh-key

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer is to remove the password required to access the ssh key so you can simply add the key in your login shell script. Which would make your system less secure and any other systems that are you use the ssh key to access.

Which is what I had to do on one system. Oddly, my ssh keys load on Ubuntu immediately upon login without the addition to my login shell script. I didn’t implement the secondary authorization requirement when generating the key, however. It really depends on how secure you need your system(s) to be.